# have_selector is failing test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am having a problem including a should have_selector problem with rspec:

This is my code:

```
describe "GET 'home'" do
  it "returns http success" do
    get 'home'
    expect(response).to be_success
  end

  it "should have the right title" do
    should have_selector("title", 
          :content => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home")
  end
end
```

I have included the following at the top:

```
RSpec.describe PagesController, :type => :controller do
  render_views
```

My html5 has the following:

```
<title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home</title>
```

and I get an error message saying:

Failures:

```
1) PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title
 Failure/Error: should have_selector("title",
   expected #<PagesController:0x007fceef586a90> to respond to `has_selector?`
 # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top  (required)>
```

Can someone help with that?

rspec -v
3.0.2

rails 4.1.1

thank you in advance.

Comment: What if remove `, :type => :controller`? I don't think it's controller spec responsibility to check page content.

Answer (score 5):

Rspec 3 does not include the capybara matchers in controller specs by default. You can change this for an individual spec by doing

```
include Capybara::RSpecMatchers
```

Or, in your spec helper

```
  config.include Capybara::RSpecMatchers, :type => :controller
```

Your next issue is that recent versions of capybara don't allow you to test for the presence of invisible elements by default, and the title element is considered to be invisible. You should use the `have_title` matcher instead.

Comment: You may also need to add `config.include Capybara::RSpecMatchers, type: :request` if you're using a _request_ spec instead of a _controller_ spec. See:  https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec

Answer (score 3):

Hollo rubyist pal!

I had this problem and that was because of two things, first I did not use capybara gem, and second have_selector only accepts one of :count, :minimum, :maximum, :between, :text, :visible, :exact, :match, :wait keys and does not understand :content.

I am sure you solved the problem, but for those who have started to learn Ruby on Rails recently and encountered such a problem I should say to eleminate it first put capybara gem in your Gemfile as below:

```ruby
group :development, :test do
  ...
  gem 'capybara'
end
```

and run command

```html
bundle install
```

then to test that your view has a specific title, in pages_controller_spec.rb file write

```ruby
describe "GET #home" do
  ...
  it "should have the right title" do
    get :home
    expect(response.body).to have_selector('title', :text => 'Ruby on Rails rocks')
  end
end
```

I hope it would help someone.

Cheerio!

Answer (score 0):

Checking content is view spec...
And controller spec means checking response status/path, render page/partials, instance variable filters params.